# Dealing with a time-based constraint in A-star on 2D grid world

Tags: algorithm, search, graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I began with a graph of 2D grid-world specifying the nodes and edges; and was given a start and goal. I was able to use A* to find the shortest path.

Now the problem was slightly modified in that concept of time was introduced and waiting at current node was allowed. The given problem can be considered with an exmaple as follows.

Suppose there are nodes in a linear world in form of an array a(1:6).
Agent has to start at 2 and go to 6. As said before, i was able to plan this using A*. Optimal path is: 2->3->4->5->6.

But suppose now time enters the picture. Each transition like 3->4 means 1 time unit has passed. Agent begins moving at time t=0 and is told that it cannot go to node 5 at time t=3. So now the optimal path is: 2->3->4->4->5->6

But i am unable to think how to use A* to produce this plan. My idea was this: I will plan in 3 dimensions = (x,y,t) rather than just (x,y). A* can anyway handle any dimensions as long as graph structure is preserved.

however, i was confused because i know start as (2,0) where i use the convention (node, time). But what is the goal? I know it is something like: (6,t). But i don't know what t? So anytime i want to calculate my heuristic from a current node to the goal, I am stumped because i don't know what the goal is? How to handle this problem using A*. This example is only representative and highly simplified. I am working in 2D world but the problem is same as described in the example.

Citing some research paper where such problems are dealt will be very helpful but please try to avoid citing research that is clearly an overkill for this problem. If someone can give pseudocode that would be the best.

Comment: Your 3D approach I think is the correct, and don't expand nodes which have a restriction `t > current t`. I think the time is not involved in your solution: you just have to reach the solution node, not in a specific time. Thus, just compare if it is your goal node, and not the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your model isn't completely dynamic and you know the changes beforehand, You can find your path by these simple changes to A* algorithm: 
First when you expand a state you always consider that you can stay at that node. 
Second when you are adding neighbors of a state to your fringe list you should check the constraints of the time and place you mentioned in your question:

```
state: position, time, h

current_state = priority_queue.top
priority_queue.add( state( current_state.position, current_state.time+1, new_h) )
for each neighbor of current state:
   if possible to be at neighbor.position at current_state.time+1
        priority_queue.add( state(neighbor.position, current_state.time+1, h) )
```

However if your world is completely dynamic you should implement a dynamic A* algorithm something like D*. Or you can run A* on the initial model and then whenever you encounter an obstacle in the middle of your path, you try to find a new path with A* while changing the map with respect to the obstacle.

Comment: And how to calculate h ? That is my another issue how do you calculate the cost (g) and heuristic (h) ? For 2d world, it was very easy but now for time-extended states, what should we do?

Comment: I guess `cost` here is equal to `time`. And `h` could be anything as long as it isn't optimistic. For example you can use Manhattan distance here.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2

`h` can be anything as long as it isn't *pessimistic*, not as long as it isn't *optimistic*. It should be admissible (it should not overestimate the cost), but it's fine if it underestimates the cost (which would be optimistic).

Also, Manhattan distance is not necessarily admissible. The OP did not specify if the 2D grid is 4-connected or 8-connected. If it's 8-connected (meaning that diagonal movement is allowed), using Manhattan distance as heuristic is **not** correct, and Euclidean distance should be used instead

Comment: @user_1_1_1 many implementations of A* (such as pseudocode on wikipedia) involve a closed list, used to avoid re-visiting nodes that have already been investigated previously. You'll want to make sure you also take the time variable into account when checking if a node is in the closed list (include the time variable of a node in your operation checking if a new node is equal to one already in the closed list)

Comment: @DennisSoemers So what i did is that i implemented nodes to be expanded as instances of a structure such that first node has `x,y,t` attributes like `nodes(1).x`, etc. There is a unique id attribute `nodes(1).id`. Whenever a node is expanded to compute its neighbors, i put the `id` to the closed list and whenever i want to check if a node belongs to closed list, i have to loop over all IDs and see if the node determined by it matches the node whose membership in closed list is to be tested? If this not efficient, am open to choosing other detailed correct answers!

Comment: @user_1_1_1 That implementation should result in the algorithm finding correct results, but it's not very efficient, because it involves looping through the entire closed list every time you look at a new node.

Normally for a 2D grid I'd recommend simply keeping a 2D grid of booleans of equal size, and marking in that grid if a corresponding node is closed. That won't work for you because of the t paramter though. I think the best option for you is storing your ''closedlist'' as a Hash Set, so that you can check if elements are in there in O(1) time